# Determine Version of .NET Software Running

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This may be a stupid question and/or a futile effort -- you've been warned...

I have a ASP .NET application (with the VB parts compiled to a DLL). This application has been around a while and the person who wrote it apparently messed up the old source code repository system. He is no longer around and I'm not clear on whether the source code I was given was a re-write or an older version (or by some strange luck the actual version of the website running).

Being that part of this website is running as a DLL, what is the best way I can go about in determining if the version of the source code I have matches what is running? I'm unable to setup an IIS server to throw this on (licensing/server cost/time/etc).

Is there a better way than compiling the project and then finding some disassembler and doing a comparison?

Comment: Tools like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) will give you C# or VB source.

Comment: You CAN get an assembly's version, but that alone will not guarantee that it corresponds to the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way than compiling the project and then finding some disassembler and doing a comparison?

That's what I've done in the past in your situation.

1. Open each compiled assembly using ILSpy, and use the option "File / Save Code" to generate source files.
2. Build the source code from your source code repository, and use ILSpy to generate source files.
3. Compare the results of 1 and 2.

Obviously this won't give you the whole picture - you'll also need to compare aspx files, config files, ..., but it's the only approach I know.